# Метод codePointAt() в Java

Tags: java

Есть ли разница в использовании методов

```
static int codePointAt(CharSequence seq, int index)
```

из класса `Character`
и

```
int codePointAt(int index)
```

из класса `String` (кроме того, что в первом используется `CharSequence`)? Результат возвращают вроде бы один и тот же.

Comment: `String` реализует интерфейс `CharSequence`, но он не единственный класс, который это делает. Например, `CharBuffer` или `StringBuilder` тоже реализуют этот интерфейс. Разница между методами в том, что `codePointAt()` из класса `String` работает только со строками, а `codePointAt()` из `CharSequence` с любыми объектами, реализующими интерфейс `CharSequence`. Возможно, реализация у них тоже различна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные методы незначительно отличаются реализацией при доступе к символам.

Пример (для Open JDK 8):

- [`Character.codePointAt(CharSequence seq, int index)`](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/Character.java#L4865-L4874):
  Вызывает метод `CharSequence::charAt` для заданного входного аргумента `seq`

```java
public static int codePointAt(CharSequence seq, int index) {
    char c1 = seq.charAt(index);
    if (isHighSurrogate(c1) && ++index < seq.length()) {
        char c2 = seq.charAt(index);
        if (isLowSurrogate(c2)) {
            return toCodePoint(c1, c2);
        }
    }
    return c1;
}
```

Соответственно, для строки реализация метода [`String::charAt`](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L656-L661) сводится к проверке индекса и прямому доступу через внутренний массив символов `char[] value`:

```java
// String::charAt
public char charAt(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= value.length)) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
    return value[index];
}
```

- [`String::codePointAt`](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L685-L690):
  Фактически он просто проверяет индекс, чтобы выбросить особое исключение `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` при выходе за пределы строки и вызывает статический метод `Character.codePointAtImpl` (доступный по умолчанию только в пакете `java.lang`), передавая в него ссылку на внутренний массив символов данной строки:

```java
public int codePointAt(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= value.length)) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
    return Character.codePointAtImpl(value, index, value.length);
}
```

Аналогично, реализация метода [`Character.codePointAtImpl`](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/Character.java#L4934-L4943) напрямую обращается по индексу к элементам массива:

```java
static int codePointAtImpl(char[] a, int index, int limit) {
    char c1 = a[index];
    if (isHighSurrogate(c1) && ++index < limit) {
        char c2 = a[index];
        if (isLowSurrogate(c2)) {
            return toCodePoint(c1, c2);
        }
    }
    return c1;
}
```

---

То есть, вызов метода `String::codePointAt` несколько эффективнее, так как позволяет избежать двойной проверки выхода за пределы массива символов, которая происходит при двойном вызове метода `String::charAt`.